# Issue with Open Shift Origin Mongo DB service

Tags: openshift-origin

I have installed OpenShift Origin V3 on aws ec2(Fedora19) using oo-install.The set up is One Broker +One Node.

I was making some modifications to the security groups to make it more restrictive - 
and it ended up some issues in the mongo service.

1.service mongod does not start up and the status shows failed.

1. The /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log says
   Thu Mar  6 11:24:08.189 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:99 Cannot assign requested address for socket: :27017
   Thu Mar  6 11:24:08.189 [initandlisten] now exiting
2. Running oo-accept-broker -v says

FAIL: error logging into mongo db:   MOPED: Retrying connection to primary for replica set :27017">]>:  MOPED: Retrying connection to primary for replica set :27017">]>/MOPED: --username Retrying, exit code: 1

Any pointers on how to resolve this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Shabna

Answer (score 0):

I would try rolling back your changes to the security groups first and then make the changes one by one and see which one causes the issue, then post that to stack and see if anyone can comment on the specific change that is affecting mongodb.